# what are you doing since morning

Tags: grammar, sentence-usage

i know that my title may not be correct but i couldn’t know correctly title .
my Duty or work started from morning until evening, if someone would ask me about it, how could he/she ask me?

> what are you working since morning?(i know it is present continues)

or

> what have you done since morning?

or

> what have you been doing since morning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would ask: "What have you been doing since (the) morning?"

"What are you doing" suggests it's still happening, but they're asking about an earlier time, what happened before, so you use the past tense: "what have you been doing" (or, if it's totally finished: "what did you do last week").

The difference between uncountable "morning" and countable "the morning" is rather subtle, but in this case, you could use either one.

Note: "What are you working?" implies that "work" is a transitive verb (requiring a grammatical object), but in this sense it is not. (You're not "working something", you're just "working".) Compare the question: "What are you eating?" (You must be eating *something*.)